# Write concurrency to mysql DB in golang

Tags: mysql, mongodb, go, concurrency, amazon-sqs

I'm working with a background job but i haven't more experience.

I have a aws sqs(message queue) service receive  message from another service. Each 3 minutes, we will receive about 300 messages from queue to process, canculate, after that write to DB.

Each message loss a bout 5 minutes to completed.

But max_connections setting of DB is about 100, so i think i need limit concurrency write data to DB.

I thinking about 2 way:

1- using a buffer channel and write a wokerpool to process.

2- seperated write process: create another message queue, after calculate data then send message to write DB, get max limit 10~15 message to process.

In 2 way above, after calculate i will save in  mongoDB before save to mysqlDB.

Way to better to implement or another way to handle?

I'm try with options 1,but have any problem if have more than 10 thousand gorountine waiting send to channel.(other than memory)

Comment: If you only want to limit the max number of connections to MySQL (and you don't need additional rate limiting), you can use connection pooling with a maximum pool size. For the standard library `database/sql` package, you can use the `SetMaxOpenConns` [function](https://pkg.go.dev/database/sql#DB.SetMaxOpenConns) on the `sql.DB` struct (which is a connection pool) to set the max pool size.

Comment: @phonaputer, i'm not set SetMaxOpenConns, in library sql of golang if not set, it default unlimitted.

Answer (score 0):

1. Use SetMaxOpenConns of database/sql package
2. Use Goroutine Pool like sync.Pool or SetLimit of errgroup package or other
   one table one goroutine
3. Use Array insert and transaction lock control
   start transaction;
   insert into table... values(),(),...();
   commit transaction;